# Pytorch - Use parts or segments of existing models

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I have a "how to do" question about Pytorch.

Suppose I have two models in Pytorch, and I want to input in the second model an output that comes out of the middle of the first model. **But** the first model is not sequential, it's very complex and may have inner branches. Toy example:

[image: Model description]

> How can I make a **version/subclass/copy of model 1** that outputs both the final and the middle tensors?

### What I could do so far?

So far, the only way I found was to know the entire model and all its `forward` connections, so I replicate the `forward` method exactly and make it output the desired middle tensor.

But this is very troublesome, as I don't really want to rebuild entire models with high complexity. This is too much prone to errors.

Is there any easier way, like it's done in Keras, for instance?

### See how easily it's done in Keras

Just get the middle layer's output and put it as an output of a new model based on model1:

```
middleTensor = model1.get_layer(layer_name).output #or model1.layers[i]
newModel1 = Model(model1.input, [middleTensor,model1.output])
```

Now I have a version of model 1 that outputs both the final and the middle tensors without any effort to deeply understand or replicate it.

> Is there any similar approach in pytorch?

Comment: have you looked at forward_hook?

Comment: Sounds like the way to go by reading the docs, but examples and "how to" are totally lacking.